# Match to symbols from file in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, xml

I have a map where each feature of a polygon shapefile will be filled with a different image. I have those images stored as PNG files. In my shapefile, each feature has a name which is the same as its corresponding png file.

There are over 180 features, and while I can select each feature separately and fill them with the raster image, I saw this function in the Advanced button and thought maybe this would be an easier way to do it. It requires an XML file.

But I have no idea what the structure of this xml file would be.

What are the tags?

How do you associate a file?

I cannot find any material on this anywhere online.

Comment: Perhaps you mean SLD

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to do it with the "Match to symbols from file" but if your feature have a field with a name that match those of your PNG you could use the data defined properties for the path of your PNG (click on the button right of the selector for the raster file path and edit the expression.

Something like this should work (didn't try):

`'C:\\path_to_your_PNG_Folder\\' ||  "Field_with_png_name"  || '.png'`

(you have to escape the \ by doubling it)